# Nested OR function in validation

Tags: formula, validation-rule, validation

We're trying to add another validation to require either
`ISBLANK(Commission_Percentage__c) OR ISBLANK(Commission_Amount__c)`, since they only have to complete one of these fields in addition to the ones below (offer targeting, live date and Expiration date).  Appreciate any suggestions.

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'legal review'),
    RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Merchant',
    OR(
        ISBLANK(Amount),
        ISPICKVAL(Offer_Targeting__c, ''),
        ISBLANK(Live_Date__c),
        ISBLANK(Expiration_Date__c)
    )
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). To help you out, could let us know what you've tried so far and what errors you got when you tried it. Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Validation rules trigger when the result of the formula is true.

### What I think you need

So unless you want to prevent *both* fields from being filled in (i.e. your users must *only fill one of those fields*), then you're actually looking to add an `AND()` to this formula instead of an `OR()`.

That is to say, the problem is when both fields are blank.

e.g.

```
AND(
    /* other stuff removed */
    OR(
        AND(
            ISBLANK(Commission_Percentage__c),
            ISBLANK(Commission_Amount__c)
        ),
        ISBLANK(Amount),
        ISPICKVAL(Offer_Targeting__c, ''),
        /* other stuff removed */
    )
)
```

The position of the nested function doesn't particularly matter.

```
OR(
    condition 1,
    AND(
        condition 4,
        condition 5
    ),
    condition 2,
    condition 3
)
```

would work, as would

```
OR(
    condition 1,
    condition 2,
    condition 3,
    AND(
        condition 4,
        condition 5
    )
)
```

The `AND()`, or any other function for that matter, is treated as just another parameter to the `OR()` function. As long as you have a comma to separate each parameter (and the function returns a boolean), it'll work.

### But if you truly mean exactly as you've said

If you do truly mean that only a maximum of one of those fields may be filled in then instead of

```
AND(
    ISBLANK(Commission_Percentage__c),
    ISBLANK(Commission_Amount__c)
)
```

you would use

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Commission_Percentage__c)),
    NOT(ISBLANK(Commission_Amount__c))
)
```

which could be simplified/rearranged using [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to

```
NOT(
    OR(
        ISBLANK(Commission_Percentage__c),
        ISBLANK(Commission_Amount__c)
    )
)
```

which is slightly less typing (and less typing is generally better, less chance of making a mistake).